# How to convert SRT (text based subtitle) to DVB (Bitmap based subtitle)?

Tags: subtitle, dvb

I have Live stream with video and audio substream , I want to add third stream of subtitle as srt subtitle stream and generate output stream with dvb subtitle stream along with video and audio.

Here I can able convert add third stream (srt subtitle stream) in output stream as dvb subtitle.Third stream with dvb subtitle generated but not able to see subtitle data in VLC player.Here proble is ffmepg can not able to convert srt datra to dvb subtitle data, ffmpeg only able to convert "srt to srt" or "dvb(Bitmap) to dvb(Bitmap)" my concern is how to transcode (convert) srt subtitle data to dvb subtitle (BITMAP format) data.Need some logic or idea to step foreword.

Or any other way to doing this?

I have tried some tool that convert srt to dvb(Bitmap) format and add that converted file as input in ffmpeg , This way I can able to create third stream as dvb subtitle even I can able to see subtitle in VLC.Now I want to convert with my own as I my input stream is LIVE stream.I can't use tool to convert it need some proper logic to convert it.

I have tried multiple ffmpeg command to convert srt to dvb format but ffmepg have written code if input and output format of subtitle  is same, no code I have found in ffmpeg that able to convert srt to dvb subtitle.

Comment: So you want to add a DVB stream, rather than hardcore/burn the subs with an overlay?

Comment: Can you post the `ffmpeg` commands that you have already tried?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @LegendofPedro , Yes I want to add third stream as dvb subtitle stream.But my input data is text (srt format), ffmpeg able to convert dvb to dvb only or srt to srt only. Here i want srt to dvb.

Comment: Thanks You @LegendofPedro,Yes I want to add third stream as dvb stream.But my i/p data (srt format), ffmpeg able to convert dvb to dvb or srt to srt.Here I want srt to dvb.
ffmpeg cmnd

 ./ffmpeg  -i "I/pLiveStream"  -i "srtTodvbConverted.sub" -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1:0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec dvbsub -f mpegts -mpegts_flags  -metadata  "udp://10.103.2.192:1236"
. I have converted srt to dvb subtitle file "srtTodvbConverted.sub" by tool "AVIADDSubs",If any idea that I can convert srt to dvb by ffmpeg, I don't want tool to convert it.!
-Simply I want to convert srt to bitmap file.